# Why didn't the Doctor use the key to teleport the TARDIS back to him?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

There! I've started watching *Doctor Who* a few weeks ago, and I've noticed some, let's say, "plot holes". In "Father's Day" we were shown that the TARDIS' key could be used to teleport it. But in later episodes where the TARDIS wasn't accessible for various reasons, the Doctor didn't try to use the key at all. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Plot holes?!  In *Doctor Who*?!  Say it isn't so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of the episode is wrong.

When Rose saved her father's life she created a paradox. There were two different histories, one where Pete died, and the other where Pete lived.

In the 'Pete lived'  history, Rose and the Doctor never came back to see him. But if they  didn't come back, they couldn't have saved him, so he died.  But if he died, they would have come back, and so on.  Time keeps flipping back and forth between the two histories.

And the TARDIS was in-between having come back, and having not come back. It was partly there, but not quite there.

The Doctor was trying to use the key to bring the TARDIS fully into his timeline.

He can't do it in other stories, because the situation was completely different.  It was never a case of teleporting the TARDIS from one location to another.

Also, note,  his attempt *failed*. He did not succeed in bringing the TARDIS to him.